# Proper timeout nonblock socket event handling?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, unix

I don't see these sort of question asked. Which is odd because of good benefits from single threaded server applications. But how would I be able to implement a timeout system in my code when the server is in nonblock state?

Currently I'm using this method.

```
 while(true)
 {
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);
        FD_SET(server_socket, &readfds);

        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < cur_sockets.size(); i++)
        {
            uint32_t sd = cur_sockets.at(i).socket;

            if(sd > 0)
                FD_SET(sd, &readfds);

            if(sd > max_sd){
                max_sd = sd;
            }

        }

        int activity = select( max_sd + 1 , &readfds, NULL , NULL, NULL);

        if(activity < 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (FD_ISSET(server_socket, &readfds))
        {

            struct sockaddr_in cli_addr;
            uint32_t newsockfd = (uint_fast32_t)accept((int)server_socket,
                               (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr,
                               &clientlength);

            if(newsockfd < 1) {
                continue;
            }

            //Ensure we can even accept the client...
            if (num_clients >= op_max_clients) {
                close(newsockfd);
                continue;
            }

            fcntl(newsockfd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

/* DISABLE TIMEOUT EXCEPTION FROM SIGPIPE */
#ifdef __APPLE__
            int set = 1;
            setsockopt(newsockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_NOSIGPIPE, (void *) &set, sizeof(int));
#elif __LINUX__
                        signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
#endif
            /* ONCE WE ACCEPTED THE CONNECTION ADD CLIENT TO  */
            num_clients++;

            client_con newCon;
            newCon.socket = newsockfd;
            time_t ltime;
            time(&ltime);
            newCon.last_message = (uint64_t) ltime;

            cur_sockets.push_back(newCon);
        }

        handle_clients();
 }
```

As you can tell, I've added a unix timestap to the client when they successfully connected. I was thinking of maybe adding another thread that sleeps every 1 second, and simply checks if any clients haven't made any sends for the max duration, but I'm afraid I'll run into bottlenecking because of the second thread locking up constantly when dealing with large amounts of connections.

Thank you,

Ajm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last argument for select is the timeout for the select call and the return code of select tells you, if it returned because a socket was ready or because of a timeout.

In order to implement your own timeout handling for all sockets you could have a time stamp for each socket and update it on any socket operation. Then before calling select compute the timeout for each socket and use the minimal value for the timeout of the select call. This is just the basic idea and one can implement it more efficient so that you don't need to recompute all timeouts before calling select. But I consider a separate thread overkill.

Comment: Hey thanks! Cant believe the answer was pretty much right in front of me.